# Unable to access static member from static function

Tags: c++, struct, static

I am using the below code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Entity
{
    static int x,y;
    
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << x << " Yoo -- ooY " << y << std::endl;
    }
};
// int Entity::x;
// int Entity::y;
int main() {
    Entity::print();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error on trying to run this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ItfG3m/ccKGCJ5N.o: in function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `Entity::x'
/usr/bin/ld: prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x31): undefined reference to `Entity::y'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I uncomment this, it works fine:

```
// int Entity::x;
// int Entity::y;
```

Shouldn't a static method be able to access static variables? Why is a declaration needed?

Comment: This isn't an access problem (compile time); it's an *existence* problem (link time). You declared, but never *defined* your static members `x` and `y`. I.e. outside of your class `int Entity::x, Entity::y;` They gotta live *somewhere*. Refer to your reference materials on C++ static member vars and how to declare+define them. Any basic text should include said information, and if yours doesn't it isn't worth the paper it's printed on.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for pointing out. If for some reason I am not able to or not want to _define_  it outside my class/struct. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *Is there a way to to use an undefined variable?*  **No.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define storage for the static variables:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Entity
{
    static int x,y; // <-- declares that variables exist somewhere
    
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << x << " Yoo -- ooY " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

int Entity::x = 0; // <-- defines storage
int Entity::y = 0; // <-- defines storage

int main() {
    Entity::print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based on your and [WhozCraig's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948759/unable-to-access-static-member-from-static-function/67948934#comment120099634_67948759) closing this question